# Setting up a Separate Monitoring Cluster for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I'm trying to setup a separate cluster (kibanacluster) for monitoring my primary elasticsearch cluster (marveltest). Below are the ES, Marvel and Kibana versions I'm using. The ES version is fixed for the moment. I can update or downgrade the other components if needed.

- kibana-4.4.1
- elasticsearch-2.2.1
- marvel-agent-2.2.1

The monitoring cluster and Kibana are both running in the host 192.168.2.124 and the primary cluster is running in a separate host 192.168.2.116.

**192.168.2.116: elasticsearch.yml**

```
marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts: ["192.168.2.124"]
marvel.enabled: true
marvel.agent.exporters:

id1:
    type: http
    host: ["http://192.168.2.124:9200"]
```

Looking at the `DEBUG` logs in the monitoring cluster i can see data is coming from the primary cluster but is getting "filtered" since the cluster name is different.

> [2016-07-04 16:33:25,144][DEBUG][transport.netty ] [nodek] connected
>   to node [{#zen_unicast_2#}{192.168.2.124}{192.168.2.124:9300}]
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:25,144][DEBUG][transport.netty ] [nodek] connected
>   to node [{#zen_unicast_1#}{192.168.2.116}{192.168.2.116:9300}]
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:25,183][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [nodek]
>   [1] filtering out response from
>   {node1}{Rmgg0Mw1TSmIpytqfnFgFQ}{192.168.2.116}{192.168.2.116:9300},
>   not same cluster_name [marveltest]
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:26,533][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [nodek] [1] filtering out response from
>   {node1}{Rmgg0Mw1TSmIpytqfnFgFQ}{192.168.2.116}{192.168.2.116:9300},
>   not same cluster_name [marveltest]
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:28,039][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [nodek] [1] filtering out response from
>   {node1}{Rmgg0Mw1TSmIpytqfnFgFQ}{192.168.2.116}{192.168.2.116:9300},
>   not same cluster_name [marveltest]
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:28,040][DEBUG][transport.netty ] [nodek] disconnecting from
>   [{#zen_unicast_2#}{192.168.2.124}{192.168.2.124:9300}] due to explicit
>   disconnect call
>   [2016-07-04 16:33:28,040][DEBUG][discovery.zen ]
>   [nodek] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true],
>   filter_data[false])
>   --> ping_response{node [{nodek}{vQ-Iq8dKSz26AJUX77Ncfw}{192.168.2.124}{192.168.2.124:9300}],
>   id[42], master
>   [{nodek}{vQ-Iq8dKSz26AJUX77Ncfw}{192.168.2.124}{192.168.2.124:9300}],
>   hasJoinedOnce [true], cluster_name[kibanacluster]}
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:28,053][DEBUG][transport.netty ] [nodek] disconnecting from
>   [{#zen_unicast_1#}{192.168.2.116}{192.168.2.116:9300}] due to explicit
>   disconnect call [2016-07-04 16:33:28,057][DEBUG][transport.netty ]
>   [nodek] connected to node
>   [{nodek}{vQ-Iq8dKSz26AJUX77Ncfw}{192.168.2.124}{192.168.2.124:9300}]
>
> [2016-07-04 16:33:28,117][DEBUG][discovery.zen.publish ] [nodek]
>   received full cluster state version 32 with size 5589

Comment: What is the unicast configuration in both clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing the use of [Marvel 1.x settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/marvel-1.3/stats-export.html) with [Marvel 2.2 settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/2.2/configuration.html), but also your other configuration seems to be off as Andrei pointed out in the comment.

```
marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts: ["192.168.2.124"]
```

This isn't a setting known to Marvel 2.x. And depending on your copy/paste, it's also possible that the YAML is malformed due to whitespace:

```
marvel.agent.exporters:

id1:
    type: http
    host: ["http://192.168.2.124:9200"]
```

This should be:

```
marvel.agent.exporters:
  id1:
    type: http
    host: ["http://192.168.2.124:9200"]
```

As Andrei was insinuating, you have likely added the production node(s) to your `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`, which attempts to join it with their cluster. I suspect you can just delete that setting altogether in your *monitoring* cluster.

```
[2016-07-04 16:33:26,533][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [nodek] [1] filtering out response from {node1}{Rmgg0Mw1TSmIpytqfnFgFQ}{192.168.2.116}{192.168.2.116:9300}, not same cluster_name [marveltest]
```

This indicates that it's ignoring a node that it is connecting too because the *other* node (`node1`) isn't in the same cluster.

---

To setup a Separate Monitoring cluster, it's pretty straight forward, but it requires understanding the moving parts first.

1. You need a separate cluster with *at least* one node (most people get by with one node).

   - This separate cluster effectively has no knowledge about the cluster(s) it monitors. It only receives data.
2. You need to send the data from the *production* cluster(s) to that separate cluster.
3. The monitoring cluster interprets that the data using Kibana + Marvel UI plugin to display charts.

So, what you need:

- Your production cluster needs to install `marvel-agent` on each node.
- Each node needs to configure the exporter(s):

This is the same as you had before:

```
marvel.agent.exporters:
  id1:
    type: http
    host: ["http://192.168.2.124:9200"]
```

- Kibana should talk to the monitoring cluster (`192.168.2.124` in this example) and Kibana needs the same version of the Marvel UI plugin.